# How to read delta table inside Azure Functions using python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm Currently working on Azure Functions where I need to read delta table from ADLS GEN2 directly. is there any way that I can use it like Azure SDK's or other alternatives ?

Comment: did you find any solution? @MJ029